# React Native - Stack Navigation and TabNavigation ( The component for route must be a React component )

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

I'm trying to make a StackNavigator that can navigate into a TabNavigator. But there is an error saying; " The component for route must be a React component ".

The TabNav is not a file folder, I just want to call it once the user login. So that, the tabs will be display I think. And also, I just follow a tutorial to make this. Sorry, guys I'm just a newbie.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIvN5.png)

Here is my code

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Login from './components/Login';
import ManageOrder from './components/ManageOrder';
import SpecialOrder from './components/SpecialOrder';
import categories from './components/categories';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <RootNav />
    );
  }
}

const RootNav = StackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
  },
  TabNav: { screen: TabNav },

});

const TabNav = TabNavigator({
  categories: {
    screen: categories,
  },
  ManageOrder: {
    screen: ManageOrder
  },
  SpecialOrder: {
    screen: SpecialOrder
  },
});
```

Comment: I suggest commenting out all the routes, and then uncomment one at a time until you find the one that is causing problems.

Answer (score 3):

You must declare all the components before calling them for examle before calling tab navigation from stack you must have to declare the tab const first see code below

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import categories from './components/categories';
import ManageOrder from './components/ManageOrder';
import SpecialOrder from './components/SpecialOrder';
import Login from './components/Login';

const TabNav = TabNavigator({
  categories: {
    screen: categories,
  },
  ManageOrder: {
    screen: ManageOrder
  },
  SpecialOrder: {
    screen: SpecialOrder
  },
});

const RootNav = StackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
  },
  TabNav: { screen: TabNav },
});
```

This should work

Comment: I don't any errors now, but I don't see any Tab Navigation. Please Help. I only see an arrow at the top, no tab navigation

Comment: since your default initial route in stacknavigator is Login screen therefore add some text in it and if login screen is displaying or not. I will also recommend to add some console statment to screen so that whenever screen will load you can see the console and becomes sure that screen has loading

Comment: I will re-open my question because there's a different problem.

Comment: @Violet I will suggest mark it answered and create new question so that other can also take get answer of same type of question without any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are not exporting any of one component.Please check it

Answer (score 0):

The problem may have been due to the updated API of react-navigation version 2. TabNavigator and StackNavigator should be replaced by createTabNavigator and createStackNavigator. I made the same mistake starting out while watching a tutorial.

v2 API: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html